# Botón no funciona Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy empezando a programar en Java y me he metido de lleno en Android. Cuando intento hacer una acción con un botón simplemente no hace nada, por ejemplo si pongo un toast como accion, el toast no se ejecuta, no da error, pero tampoco funciona. 
Esta es una de las maneras que he intentado sin resultado:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

Button btnAccess;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accessButton);
    btnAccess.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pulsao!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Parece estar bien, pero si no funciona es que esta mal.

---

Añado el XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:backgroundTint="#00272121"
android:foregroundTint="#1E1616"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/accessButton"
    android:layout_width="165dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:text="ACCEDER"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hola, el .xml es el de activity_main.xml ? si es así entonces el problema solo es que no estas permitiendo desde la configuración de tu android mostrar notificaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Si no funciona, el problema **se debe a que dentro del layout `activity_main.xml` no se encuentra un botón con id `accessButton`**.

Seguramente se encuentra el botón en el proyecto, pero en otro layout y no en el que carga la Activity que es en este caso debe ser activity_main.xml.

---

Actualización:

Si el botón se encuentra en el layout correcto, el problema se debe a que tienes desactivadas las notificaciones, en este caso también los mensajes Toast son desactivados, por esta razón no se  muestran.

[Cómo activar o desactivar las notificaciones en un dispositivo Android](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=es&oco=0)

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que el boton si este escuchando, pero el toast no se ejecuta, 
En el toast puse this en el contexto, mira haber si te funciona.
'''
btnAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accessButton); btnAccess.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { Toast.makeText(this,"Pulsao!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } });'''